# How to locate a webelement inside another webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image][image]

I have a situation like in the picture where i have several class='ratings' and inside that i have class='rating_likes'. so for some ratings there is rating_likes and some doesnt have then . i want to locate 'rating_likes' of first "rating" and check if the statement (x perople found this helpful is there or not) if its not there . i click on "helpful" and check if the ocunt increases.

my porblem is when i do  static final WebLocator ratingLikes = WebLocator.className("rating__likes" it finds rating likes for all the ratings . so i do ratingLikes.get(0); but the issue is if first ratings doesnt have rating likes, it picks the first ratings which has rating likes.

i tried my best but i couldnt come up with something where i can check ratings specifically in first rating class.

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Post your relevant Html or url and your code trial?

Comment: i have added a picture of the html